# Z-Index of leaflet default control box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I want to change the Z-Index of the default layer control box.

[image: The Table covers the control box and becomes unclickable]

When the Table appears, I can not alternate between the layers since the table becomes on top of the leaflet control box.

PS: I purposely set the table z-index to a number because when entering full screen, it doesn't show. The leaflet control box always shows on the full screen even without setting its Z-index. So I would like to make it between both.

```
var baseLayers = {
        "SASPlanet": SASPlanet,
        "GMapCatcher": GMapCatcher
    };

    var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, {},{
        collapsed:false,
    }).addTo(map);
```

Table:

```
<div id = "markerAndList">
    <div class="row full">
        <div class="col col-sm-3 full" style="position: absolute;top: 90px;right: 0px;z-index:1000;">
            <h3 >Geodesic Points</h3>  
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Code</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody id="t_points"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @Addis: Added some code. Although the question might not need some

Comment: The layers control has a CSS class of `leaflet-control-layers`, you can experiment with the z-index on that.

Comment: @peeebeee That worked! Thanks.